# Где найти страницу "Контакты" на сайте WordPress (через ftp)

Tags: wordpress

Ломаю себе голову весь день, где мне найти эту страницу. Дело в том, что через обычное редактирование мне не поменять страницу, нужно обязательно открыть её через ftp для редактирования. Но где она находится? Может вам будет легче, если я скажу, что эта страница "контакты" создавалась через Elementor. Может не через него конечно, но он доступен для редактирования. А когда начинаешь редактировать через обычный редактор то пишет что часть или полностью страницы может быть утеряна. Непонятно... Спасибо.....
P.S читал на серче и других форумах, нужного ответа не нашел (

Comment: Ftp не поможет. Страницы хранятся в базе,  а не в файлвх.

Comment: @KAGGDesign соответственно мне нужен пароль от БД? phpMyadmin , да?

Comment: Они у вас есть. Доступы к БД в файле wp-config.php.

Comment: @KAGGDesign может я неправильно вас понял... обьясните как для нуба пожалуйста. 
В файле wp-config.php не страницы ведь, а данные для БД. Каков ход моих действий?? Нужно страницу поправить, а так и не понял, где найти её, "....com/contacts/
Заранее спасибо....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доступы к базе в файле `wp-config.php`, в строках вида

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'пароль');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Используя эти доступы, подключитесь к базе с помощью phpMyAdmin. В базе есть таблица `wp_posts`, в ней все посты. Ищите пост по `post_name` - там слаг поста, или `post_title` - там заголовок. Контент находится в поле `post_content`.